# How to add an object in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to push object into an array

I have something like these

```
for(var i=0; i<test.length; i++){
    console.log(test[i])
    console.log(items[test[i]])
    productObj.push( { test[i] : items[test[i]]} );
}
```

both console.log show stuff but I have an error on the `push()`. The error is "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`"

Can anyone help me about this weird issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object literal keys need to be constant. `test[i]` isn't going to work.  You'll need to create an empty object and add the key/value pair:

```
var o = {};
o[ test[i] ] = items[test[i]];

productObj.push( o );
```

Answer (score 2):

The keys in an object literal are not evaluated and must be valid identifiers.

You would get the same error just from the object literal: `{ test[i]: 1 }`.

You can use the `new` keyword in conjunction with an anonymous function to create the object instead:

```
productObj.push( new function () { this[test[i]] = items[test[i]]; } );
```

If you find that the above is less readable, then you should create the object in advance:

```
var temp = {};
temp[test[i]] = items[test[i]];
productObj.push( temp );
```

Answer (score 1):

The key of an entry in the `{}` syntax for creating objects is not looked up as a variable, it must be a valid identifier. `test[i]` is not a valid identifier due to the brackets, and even if it was it would not get evaluated.

To create a key from `test[i]`, you have to manually add it using the `[]` syntax.

```
var v = {};
v[test[i]] = ...
```